# How do I resize the ‘usable area’ of a tmux session?

Tags: terminal, tmux

I'm using a ‘session group’, to keep multiple OS-level, window-managed terminal windows open to different `tmux` ‘windows’ (so they share a default working-directory, `tmux` settings, etceteras.) Those Terminal windows are different sizes.

Normally, from a larger Terminal, I can do the following to start a new command:

```
:new-window vim
```

[image]

However, if I *ever* switch to a different pane with that new, larger Terminal window, I am foreverafter stuck with this, when I switch back:

[image]

I have to kill the entire session, create an entirely new session, and link it to the session-group again, using `tmux new-session -t <blah>`, to restore the full terminal-width.

Is there any other way to restore / change / set the ‘available width’ of a session (or window, idk)?

Comment: have you enabled the aggressive-resize option?  also, if two different sized clients are attached at the same time, the larger screen'd client will be forced to the smaller screen'd client.  try detaching others when attaching with a new client.

Comment: Problem is, they're attached to *different sessions*. That's exactly what I'm trying to circumvent; the problem isn't at attach-time, it's only when I switch windows.

Comment: Also, `set aggressive-resize` solves it! Add that as a real answer, and I'll give you an accept. (=

Comment: I thought that might help, glad it worked.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Perhaps enabling the aggressive-resize option will help:

```
set-window-option -g aggressive-resize
```

A good overview of tmux options is given [here](https://mutelight.org/practical-tmux).

Comment: FYI this doesn't work with iTerm2 as it states it's incompatible with this option.

Comment: What could be used in iTerm2 to overcome this?

Comment: `tmux -CC attach -d` works for iTerm2.

Answer (score 17):

When attach screen you may use detach mode

> tmux attach -d
>   with will resize screen after disconnect other clients from the sessions (and someone who used small screen)

Or you can interactively detach by pressing Ctrl-B-Shift-D

Comment: `tmux -CC attach -d` is the equivalent when using iTerm's tmux integration. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7819465/954439 for another explanation of why it works.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with tmux 3.1, the default option for `window-size` is `latest`.  So all you need to do is upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

there is also:
`tmux resize-window -A`     # to resize to the largest session or
`tmux resize-window -a`     # to the smallest session
*(or specific geometry see `man tmux |less +/resize-window`)*

(of course alternatively use `<prefix>:resize-window -a`)